# I lose the selected text while clicking the popup menu

Tags: livecode

I lose the selected text while clicking the popup menu (clicking the right button) in the textfield "MytextField". I am using this code. Choice 2 & 3 works fine because they not need the selected option, but choice 1 doesn't works. Is there any alternate way to select?.

```
on menuPick pItemName
   put the selectedText of field "MytextField" into Ftext
      switch pItemName
      case "Choice 1"
    answer Ftext
    break
 case "Choice 2"
    answer "bye"
    break
  case "Choice 3"
        answer "Please"
    break
   end switch
end menuPick
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the traversalon of the popup button to false.